# IBM Websphere commerce payment

Tags: payment-gateway, websphere-commerce

I have a situation at hand that is not supported OOB from Websphere commerce around payments.

**Scenario:**

1. User adds 1 item to cart and proceeds to checkout.
2. Provides the billing and shipping details and proceeds to payment page.
3. At my payment page once I click on place order, the payment gateway page is opened where I will be providing all the card details (not in Websphere commerce control).
4. Keeping my payment page open, user opens new tab and add another item to the cart.
5. User comes back to the payment page which was left open and complete the order.
6. The order gets completed with 2 items and not the initial 1 item that user added to proceed with payment.

**Payment page setup:**

The payment gateway page is external and is a 3-step page setup.

WebSphere Commerce (payment section) --> Payment page (external, enter card details and submit) --> OTP page --> External payment gateway confirmation page (click on continue button) --> WebSphere Commerce Order confirmation page.
At any point above, a cancel button is available on the click of which flow comes back to WebSphere Commerce pages.

**Question:**

1. How do you make the user not add another item to cart when I am already on the payment page. (Ideal flow is if they decide not to place order, they will click cancel on payment gateway page and come back to Websphere Commerce flow and can do the checkout process with modification all over again.
2. To avoid the above situation, we can lock the order so that user cannot add other items to this order. If the user decides to cancel it anyway on the payment gateway page and comes back to commerce flow, the order needs to be unlocked. Provided the user clicks on the cancel button in the payment gateway page, we can unlock the order. Now at the OTP page on payment gateway, the user decides to use the browser back button and navigate to some earlier page in history, the user has technically not cancelled the order but the order is still locked. How this scenario can be handled and the order can be unlocked?

Some insight on this use case would be really helpful. Although this is a rare situation, but it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to store data about the order such as number of items in the cart and total price as you go to the payment page(either in the orders.field1 etc or in an new table).  On order submit you can verify that the data is the same and continue if it is or take the user back to the cart with a message if it is different.  What data you save depends upon the edge scenarios you are concerned about.

If you are using the payment plugin cassettes, you can use the data stored in the payment instruction for this same purpose and do the check before the payment plugin returns.

I am sure there are other ways to handle this. More detail about the payment system, how it is called and how the payment data is being captured would help.